# How to register dll in GAC with .Net MSI

Tags: .net, dll, windows-installer, gac

When we build .net MSI, what are the steps to register the dlls in GAC? I want to msi, for copying and registering the dlls. Is it possible?

Comment: how are you creating your msi? if you use the Visual Studio setup project you have a property for the Project Output elements where you can specify the assembly should be registered in the GAC.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio to create my msi. Am I suppose to use: Add Global Assembly Cache Folder and inclue the dlls that I need? And copy other file/assemblies in respective folders?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an `VS Setup Project`

After adding your outputs and files etc.

Right click on your msi project app root and choose `view` then `File System`

Here you will see where all your files are installing and also notice a `Global Assembly Cache Folder`. By dragging and dropping the dlls you want to be in the GAC into this folder, when you running your msi it will install all of your dlls into the GAC.

**As an aside**
Be careful when installing this onto your local machine, if you are trying to run a debug routine and have a reference to a version of a dll that exist in your GAC it will use this reference instead of the one in your solution.

A fix for this is to change the version number of the relevant project in your VS solution as soon as you have added the latest version to the GAC.

Comment: Luke, that's what I wanted to know. Thanks!

Comment: Forgot something... you will have to sign your dlls to add them to the GAC

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the software you use to generate the .msi (such as a VS Setup Project, WiX, or most other tools) will provide you with an option to register the assembly in the GAC.

However, you can use [Gacutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to manually register or uninstall an assembly from the GAC.